# simple app worked locally but on host returns #368

Tags: facebook, localhost

i have made an app that posts on my fb wall. while i was developing it locally with XAMPP everything worked fine. Now i have uploaded my work on a host (000webhost if it matters) and i have bought a domain (from godaddy) which i have put on facebook settings but when i try to use the app i do get logged in successfully but i cant post anything anymore as i get back this message (#368) The action attempted has been deemed abusive or is otherwise disallowed . Anyone who has some insight as to what i should do, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can't post from another domain, in your case localhost, while having an app domain, the one you bought from godaddy.

to fix this either set your app domain to localhost on facebook, or run your scripts from the actual domain you're hosting the app on.

but running code from a different domain than the app's will cause this error. also you'll need SSL support for production.